# How can i call an object?

Tags: python, django

I have got a project with auntification.
This is my models.py:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    profile_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    photo_url = models.URLField()
```

There is a views.py:

```
@login_required
def home(request):
    return render(request, 'home.html')


def vk_callback(request):
    try:
        vk_user = UserSocialAuth.objects.get(provider='vk-oauth2', user=request.user)
        vk_profile = vk_user.extra_data
        user_info = UserInfoGetter(vk_profile['access_token'])
        pers_id, first_name, last_name, photo_url = user_info.get_vk_info()

        try:
            user_profile = Profile.objects.get(profile_id=pers_id)
        except Profile.DoesNotExist:
            user_profile = Profile.objects.create(
                profile_id=pers_id,
                first_name=first_name,
                last_name=last_name,
                photo_url=photo_url
            )

        user_profile.first_name = first_name
        user_profile.last_name = last_name
        user_profile.photo_url = photo_url
        user_profile.save()

    except UserSocialAuth.DoesNotExist:
        pass

    return redirect(home)
```

I need to take pers_id in order to pull out the values of photo, name, last_name in home. How can I do this?

Comment: What is not working with the code you provided?